# IndexError in function

Tags: python, indexing

```
def AddVct(Vct1,Vct2,VctLen):
    Vct3 = []
    n=1
    while n < VctLen:
        Vct3[n] = Vct1[n] + Vct2[n]
        n += 1
        print(Vct[n])
    return Vct3
```

The program outputs:

`IndexError: list assignment index out of range.`

How to avoid this?

Comment: `Vct3` is an empty list so you can't put a value in its 1st index. Are you sure `n` must be 1 initially instead of 0?

Comment: And you probably want `n` to start from 0, as indexing starts at 0

Comment: You could be more pythonic with this function if you would use `zip` instead while `Vct3 = [a + b for a, b in zip(Vct1, Vct2)]`

Comment: or: `map(sum, zip(Vct1, Vct2))`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign to a list element that doesn't exist. And since you start with an empty list, no elements exist in it. Generally, you would `append()` instead.

```
Vct3.append(Vct1[n] + Vct2[n])
```

Or, you could initialize `Vct3` to be the size you want beforehand:

```
Vct3 = [0] * VctLen + 1
```

Then the assignment you already have works fine.

Assuming you start with an empty list and use `append()`, list indices start at 0, so you should define `Vct3` as a single-element list so that the indices match between the input and output lists.

```
Vct3 = [None]    # or whatever you want the first value to be
```

Or else initialize `n` to 0 instead of 1 if you want to consider all the elements of the lists.

In that case, however, it would be more Pythonic to use a list comprehension

```
Vct3 = [a + b for (a, b) in zip(Vct1, Vct2)]
```

N. B. It's generally not necessary to pass in the length of a list as its own parameter. You can trivially get it using `len()`.